# Lorentz Transformation - Derivation of $\beta$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, lorentz-symmetry

How can one derive the equations for a Lorentz transformation? Is there a paper by Lorentz in which it is done? I think it is related to considering motion with respect to a beam of light. I am trying to understand how the scaling factor called $\beta$ arises.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Derivation of Lorentz Transformations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255193/)

Comment: Here's a nice set of lecture notes that derives the Lorentz transformations: http://physics.mq.edu.au/~jcresser/Phys378/LectureNotes/VectorsTensorsSR.pdf

Comment: Do you mean gamma? "gamma" is the Lorentz factor, $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ (or its inverse). "beta" is usually used to represent the velocity of something as fraction of the velocity of light, $\beta=v/c$. So $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1 - \beta^2}$

Comment: In Einstein's original 1905 paper (e.g. https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies ), he uses the symbol $\beta$ for the time-dilation factor.

Comment: (looks at p.48 of the Dover Press reprint translation) Oh. So he does.Well pointed out. But nowadays this would be considered nonstandard.